# Please explain this PHP Function Definition

Tags: php, function

*Please change the title into something that refer into this question since i didn't know what is this should be.

When i read some tutorial i see script like this

```
function testArray(array $categories) {
var_dump($categories);
}

testArray(array('string'));
```

The `array` in function definition make the parameter strict must be array, which i love it.
Then i test this script

```
function testString(string $string) {
    var_dump($string);
}

testString('test');
```

Why did i get error like this `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to testString() must be an instance of string, string given ....`?
I'm pretty sure the parameter is string.

Comment: `boolean`
`integer`
`float`
`string`
Scalar types data types.PHP does not support this types hinting.

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about Type Hinting.
PHP type hinting can only be used in objects and arrays.
String is a scalar type which does not supports type hinting

More on type hinting

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: But there is hope https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typechecking (Under Discussion) and https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hinting_with_cast (In Draft) or maybe not like https://wiki.php.net/rfc/parameter_type_casting_hints (Withdrawn).